# tinyMCE - Is it possible to modify Image Advanced Tab to include all margins (left, right, top, bottom)?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Working with TinyMCE 4 and have implemented the Insert/Image feature with the ADVANCED tab.  Is it possible to modify the Vertical and Horizontal space options to include four options instead?  These would be Left space, Right space, Top space, Bottom space?

The plugin used is, 'image code', but I don't see this in the plugins folder...?

Another question - how do I use the "Style" input field?  Can't seem to find documentation on that.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options for the `image` plugin are documented here:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/image/

The plugin is in the `image` folder in the `plugins` folder within TinyMCE.

The `Style` input field is for adding inline styles to the image.

Comment: When I add a "style" in the style input field, nothing is changed to the image html code for the image.  Do I need to include a parameter for this in the config file?  Everything else on the tab seems to work fine.